# How to determine height and length of a 2D array from stdin?

Tags: c, arrays, list, integer, stdin

My program has to read contents of a file like so:

```
name_of_program < Test.txt
```

Test.txt is a 2D array of integers (integers are separated by spaces, sometimes multiple ones, rows of integers are separated by EOL), but of unknown length and height. How do I determine them?
I plan on storing each row in a node of a linked list as an array of integers.

EDIT: My program roughly looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int *val; //stores the row
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *addnode(int *val, struct node *next);
struct node *mergesort(struct node *head, int column); //column by which I'll sort it
struct node *merge(struct node *head_one, struct node *head_two, int column);

int main(int column) //number of column to sort by, should run like that "name_of_program column < Test.txt" in Unix systems
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *current;
    struct node *next;
    head = NULL;

    /* Reading from stdin line by line, writing it to list and linking nodes - I have only the last bit done */

    head = mergesort(head, column);

    /* Writing to stdout, row by row of sorted list, I can't do that without the previous bit */

    for(current = head; current != NULL; current = next)
        next = current->next, free(current);
    return 0;
};


struct node *addnode(int *val, struct node *next)
{
    struct node *tnode;
    tnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(*tnode));
    if(tnode != NULL) {
        tnode->val = val; //not sure about this line, would it write whole array, or just one element?
        tnode->next = next;
    };
    return tnode;
}

struct node *mergesort(struct node *head, int column)
{
    struct node *head_one;
    struct node *head_two;
    if((head == NULL) || (head->next == NULL))
        return head;
    head_one = head;
    head_two = head->next;
    while((head_two != NULL) && (head_two->next != NULL)) {
        head = head->next;
        head_two = head->next->next;
    };
    head_two = head->next;
    head->next = NULL;
    return merge(mergesort(head_one, column), mergesort(head_two, column), column);
}

struct node *merge(struct node *head_one, struct node *head_two, int column)
{
    struct node *head_combined;
    if(head_one == NULL)
        return head_two;
    if(head_two == NULL)
        return head_one;
    if(head_one->val[column] < head_two->val[column]) {
        head_combined = head_one;
        head_combined->next = merge(head_one->next, head_two, column);
    } else {
        head_combined = head_two;
        head_combined->next = merge(head_one, head_two->next, column);
    };
    return head_combined;
}
```

Comment: By reading the text in and determining the number of values on a line and the total number of lines?

Comment: If the input file is a textual representation of integers with different delimiters between individual entries than between rows (eg, space separated lines), you can follow Oli's suggestion.  If the input file is just a bunch of integers, you will have a difficult time.  (If you are given 4 values, is it 2x2, 1x4, or 4x1?)  How you determine the dimensions is entirely up to you.

Comment: @WilliamPursell There are spaces (sometimes multiple) between integers in each row, and EOL between each row. I'm totally new to C, and while I kind of understand sorting algorithms (because it's more of a math than programming), the rest is black magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by reading file line by line in C you can use getline function.
You will need to allocate sufficiently large buffer considering maximum length of line.
Process the line, retrieving integers from line, this can be done by looping through line buffer 
and skipping white spaces. The integers can be stored either in 2D array or linked list which you can created.

Comment: I updated the question. I'm having problems with understanding language specifications in English, and as far as I know there are none in my native language. Could you show me how exactly should it look?